# PHP session.save_path when using database

Tags: php, session

I've just moved to storing my sessions in a database.  My PHP code uses `session_set_save_handler()` to supply the required functions and all seems to be ok.  But do I need to change my php.ini as well?  For example, `session.save_handler` still has the value of "files".  Also, do I still need to make sure that `session.save_path` points to a valid directory?

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php), then no, you don't need to specify `session.save_path`